# State not updating from NaN

Tags: reactjs

I have a very simple form that takes in `Name` and `Age`. The `Name` and `Age` state are updated `onChange`. However, once I'm done inputting name and age, at the very bottom, my `p` tags do not return the name and age.

I believe my `commonChange()` function is correct but unsure as to why the name and age is not shown once I input the data.

*My code is the following:*

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './normalize.css';
import './index.css';

class Form extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            nameValue: '',
            ageValue: ''
        }
        this.commonChange = this.commonChange.bind(this);
    }

    commonChange(event){
        this.setState(
        {
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Name and Age Return</h1>
                <form>
                    <label>Name:
                        <input type="text" name="nameValue" onChange={this.commonChange} />
                    </label><br />
                    <label>Age:
                        <input type="text" name="ageValue" onChange={this.commonChange} />
                    </label>
                </form>
                {this.props.nameValue && <p>{this.props.nameValue}</p>}
                {this.props.ageValue && <p>{this.props.ageValue}</p>}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render( < Form / > , document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: `this.props` and `this.state` are two different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both nameValue and ageValue are part of component state but not props.

Props is something you receive data from parent to the child component. State is something you manage with in the component.

So Change

```
  {this.props.nameValue && <p>{this.props.nameValue}</p>}
        {this.props.ageValue && <p>{this.props.ageValue}</p>}
```

To

```
  {this.state.nameValue && <p>{this.state.nameValue}</p>}
        {this.state.ageValue && <p>{this.state.ageValue}</p>}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `this.props.nameValue` to `this.state.nameValue` as you are getting value from state not props.